# SQL query to get lowest 3 values per column grouping by another column

Tags: sql, nosql

So i have a table that has a set of information like this

```
name     Type    PRICE
11111    XX      0.001
22222    YY      0.002
33333    ZZ      0.0001
11111    YY      0.021
11111    ZZ      0.0111
77777    YY      0.1
77777    ZZ      1.2
```

Now these numbers go on for about a million rows and there could be upwards of 20 of the same 'name' mapping to 20 different TYPE. But there will only be 1 unique type per name. What I mean by this is that 11111 could have XX,YY,ZZ on it but it cannot have YY,ZZ,YY on it.

What I need is to get the lowest 3 prices and what TYPE they are per name.

Right now I can get the lowest price per name by doing:

```
select name, type, min(price) from table group by name;
```

However that is just for the lowest price but I need the lowest 3 prices. I've been trying for a couple days and I cant seem to get it. All help is appreciated.

Also, please let me know if I forgot any information, i'm still trying to figure out stack overflow :P

Oh and the database is a noSQL that uses SQL syntax.

edit: I can't seem to get the format down for my example data from my table to show correctly

Comment: Add `type` to the `Group By` and see if it changes the results.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Since (name, type) is defined as being a unique pair, grouping by (name, type) would cause no grouping to occur.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your results and expected results?

Comment: Does NoSQL support `Top` in the `Select`? You could do `Top 3` and `Order by` the 3rd column.

Comment: @WEI_DBA wouldn't that only give 3 records?

Comment: Per your statement above `but I need the lowest 3 prices`. Yes.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Per their statement above "What I need is to get the lowest 3 prices and what TYPE they are **per name**"

Comment: Showing what the current query produces and what you really want would help.

Comment: I would have to provide more example data to do that seeing as the data that I provided would all be returned with my current query.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports window functions, and allowing for the possibility that there may be more than three rows in your data with any of the three lowest prices, this should do it:

```
select the_table.*
from 
    the_table
    inner join (
        select name, price
        from (
            select name, price, row_number() over(partition by name order by price) as rn
            from the_table) as x
        where rn < 4
        ) as y on y.name=the_table.name and y.price=the_table.price;
```

Comment: Sadly when i tried this it says i cannot do ROW_NUMBER